# JSON Post on Sinatra with Rails3

Tags: json, api, post, sinatra

I am working on APIs and I have used Sinatra and Rabl for develop APIs for Rails app.
Now I am having one issue when iOS developer post data in JSON format

The url is: '/users/2/contacts' and a post request is made to this URL

I can get all the JSON data by 
`JSON.parse env['rack.input'].read` or by 
`::MultiJson.decode(request.body)`

But I'm not able to get '2' which is the user's ID from the URL, if have an idea how to get params from url it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that `/users/2/contacts` is the URL that the JSON is POSTed to.

If routes are set up correctly you should be able to get the user's ID from `params[:id]` in your controller.

In Rails all request params are parsed and available in the `params` hash, including parsed JSON data if your content-type is correct. See [the Ruby on Rails Guide topic that covers this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters).

Comment: Sorry, unclear this was a Sinatra-specific question. Sinatra also has a params hash if you name the params in the route. See http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html.

Comment: Yes, this works if i post http data, but it doesn't work if i post JSON data

Comment: Interesting. As a last resort you could parse the query string directly - something like `CGI::parse(request.query_string)`.

Comment: hmm i have also tried same before, but it only returns query strings which is comes after '?' i.e www.abc.com/users/2/contacts?test=val&abc=xyz
So it parse the test and abc variables but not parse '2'

Comment: Duh, should have thought of that :)

Comment: @chirag.sweng can you share the `post` method for reference? A little idea about the implementation might help.